# cant connect to tor

Tags: network-configuration

```
11/22/18, 00:40:39.932 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
11/22/18, 00:40:39.932 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
11/22/18, 00:40:39.933 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
11/22/18, 00:40:39.933 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
11/22/18, 00:40:39.933 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
11/22/18, 00:40:40.660 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
11/22/18, 00:41:10.979 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 10; recommendation warn; host 24E2F139121D4394C54B5BCC368B3B411857C413 at 204.13.164.118:443) 
11/22/18, 00:41:10.980 [WARN] 10 connections have failed: 
11/22/18, 00:41:10.981 [WARN]  9 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
11/22/18, 00:41:10.990 [WARN]  1 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
11/22/18, 00:41:11.630 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
11/22/18, 00:41:11.630 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
11/22/18, 00:41:11.630 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
```

Comment: I got the same error from Orbot. My ISP is hostile to all proxy services so I'm still trying to find a way around that. Hopefully someone will provide an answer that helps both of us. I can connect to Tor, with or without a bridge, but then the connection keeps timing out so I can't go anywhere. I even had to use an evasive vpn service just to get around their block. I still can't get I2P working either. /Matthew Campbell

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to connect using bridges?
If so try getting new bridges from https://bridges.torproject.org/bridges?transport=obfs4 and make sure you paste the whole configuration line instead of just ip address and port.